# How to generate a treeview Json from a List or Dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, nested, treeview

I have the following List/Dataframe:

[['title1','title1_chapter1','title1_chapter1_section1','title1_chapter1_href1'],
['title1','title1_chapter1','title1_chapter1_section2','title1_chapter1_href2'],
['title1','title1_chapter2','title1_chapter2_section1','title1_chapter2_href1'],
['title1','title1_chapter2','title1_chapter2_section2','title1_chapter2_href2'],
['title2','title2_chapter1','title2_chapter1_section1','title2_chapter1_href1']]

I want to transform it to the following nested JSON such that it can be used in bootstrap treeview.

```
[
  {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "title1_chapter1_section1",
            "href": "title1_chapter1_href1"
          },{
            "text": "title1_chapter1_section2",
            "href": "title1_chapter1_href2"
          }],
        "text": "title1_chapter1"
      },{
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "title1_chapter2_Section1",
            "href": "title1_chapter2_href1"
          },{
            "text": "title1_chapter2_section2",
            "href": "title1_chapter2_href2"
          }],
        "text": "title1_chapter2"
      }],
    "text": "title1"
  },{
    "nodes": [
      {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "title2_chapter1_section1",
            "href": "title2_chapter1_href2"
          }],
        "text": "title2_chapter1"
      }],
    "text": "title2"
  }
]
```

How can I do it in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Converting DataFrame to JSON you can see in this [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

This is the example from the documentation

```py
import json
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]],
    index=["row 1", "row 2"],
    columns=["col 1", "col 2"],
)
result = df.to_json(orient="split")
parsed = json.loads(result)
json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
```

and the result :

```
{
    "columns": [
        "col 1",
        "col 2"
    ],
    "index": [
        "row 1",
        "row 2"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "a",
            "b"
        ],
        [
            "c",
            "d"
        ]
    ]
}
```

If the data from list you can do something like this

```py
import json

aList = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':3, 'd':4}]
jsonStr = json.dumps(aList, indent=4)
print(jsonStr)
```

The result:

```
[
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    },
    {
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4
    }
]
```

I hope this answer helping solve your problem

Comment: Thanks the reply but this cannot achieve my result.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I manage to solve it, below is the code:

```
import json
xlist = [['title1','title1_chapter1','title1_chapter1_section1','title1_chapter1_href1'],
         ['title1','title1_chapter1','title1_chapter1_section2','title1_chapter1_href2'],
         ['title1','title1_chapter2','title1_chapter2_section1','title1_chapter2_href1'],
         ['title1','title1_chapter2','title1_chapter2_section2','title1_chapter2_href2'],
         ['title2','title2_chapter1','title2_chapter1_section1','title2_chapter1_href1']]

title = xlist[0][0]
chapter = xlist[0][1]
jstr = '[{"nodes":[{"nodes":['

for x in xlist:
    if x[0] != title: 
        jstr = jstr[:-1] + f'],"text":"{chapter}"' + '}],' + f'"text":"{title}"' + '},{"nodes":[{"nodes":['
        title = x[0]
        chapter = x[1]
    elif x[1] != chapter: 
        jstr = jstr[:-1] + f'],"text":"{chapter}"' + '},{"nodes":['
        chapter = x[1]
    jstr = jstr + '{' + f'"text":"{x[2]}","href":"{x[3]}"' + '},' 

jstr = jstr[:-1] + f'],"text":"{x[1]}"' + '}],' + f'"text":"{x[0]}"' + '}]'
parsed = json.loads(jstr)
print(json.dumps(parsed,indent=2))
```

Comment: however, this looks quite messy, can it be done in a more pythonized way?
    
    if I transform the xlist to dataframe, can I use some datafram functions to achieve the same result?

`df = pd.DataFrame([{'title':x[0],'chapter':x[1], 'section':x[2], 'href':x[3]} for x in xlist ], columns=['title','chapter','section','href'])`